# Running a Motor Controller, Motor, and Raspberry Pi off the Same Power Supply

Tags: microcontroller, motor, raspberry-pi, buck, teensy

I have a 24V brushed motor, a Raspberry Pi, and a Teensy 4.1 microcontroller all running off the same power supply (a 24V tool battery). I have a step down regulator that converts 24V to 5V:

https://www.pololu.com/product/3782

I'm thinking of having the battery connected to both my motor and the regulator. I'm then thinking of having the regulator supply 5V to my Teensy (instead of via the USB port) and my Raspberry Pi.

My main concern is that the noise and occasional high torque demands of my motor will cause random voltage spikes that in turn cause my Teensy and/or Raspberry Pi to reset. Is this a valid concern, and if so, what is a solution? Would separating grounds (how could I do that) or isolating the 5V circuit help? If this isn't a concern, why isn't it?

Comment: Star grounding and power configuration, of course; maybe some extra capacitance on the 24V rail. The Pololu stuff is fairly well-made so I'd say try it without anything extra first. Is the motor being PWMed or just on/off control?

Comment: The motor is being PWMed via another motor driver breakout board from Pololu (https://www.pololu.com/product/2994), which is being controlled by the Teensy. Star grounding and power sounds good. It looks like the ground of the regulator breakout board is shared by both the input 24V and the output 5V, but I don't think that should be an issue, right?

Comment: Should not be an issue. I've made a setup around that motor controller board that's very similar to what you're doing and have had no issues on several units running continuously for years and years.

Comment: Great, thank you!!